# Sorting ArrayList of TreeSets

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections, treeset

I have an ArrayList of TreeSets defined like this (in Java) where n is some given number.

```
ArrayList<TreeSet<Integer>>(n)
```

Since I know that all values inside TreeSet are sorted in ascending order, that keep my List unsorted. Now I want to sort my List based on the first Element of each TreeSet in order to have both list and all treesets sorted.

Is it possible to sort just these elements which I get using list.get(i)? Will this mess up my TreeSets too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that you already have an `ArrayList<TreeSet<Integer>>` initialized; we'll call it `list`.

You'll have to pass a custom `Comparator<TreeSet<Integer>>` to sort each `TreeSet<Integer>`:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(TreeSet::first));
```

This sorts the `ArrayList<TreeSet<Integer>>` in ascending order according to the first element of each `TreeSet<Integer>`.

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for. After this call i will have my list sorted? So I can basically call it just like that?

Comment: Yes, the list with be sorted!

Comment: Also keep in mind that Java 8 is required for this method.

Answer (score 2):

You can try sorting your `ArrayList` using a custom comparator.  In this case, your custom comparator can compare the first numbers from each of two tree set elements.

```
Collections.sort(list, new ListOfTreeSetComparator());

class ListOfTreeSetComparator implements Comparator<TreeSet<Integer>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(TreeSet<Integer> ts1, TreeSet<Integer> ts2) {
        return ts1.first().compareTo(ts2.first());
    }
}
```

Note that there is a potential problem with your logic.  Just because the *first* elements in each `TreeSet` have ascending order in your `ArrayList` does not necessarily mean that all elements would be sorted.

Comment: Here is my logic (correct me if I am wrong): I have ts1 and ts2. When I type 
`    ts1.add(2)
     ts1.add(1)
     ts1.add(4)

    ts2.add(3)
    ts2.add(5)

`
Result will be ts1(1,2,4) and ts2(3,5). Now when I add these treesets into my list, looking only first elements, than list would look like this : (1,3) which is sorted ?

Answer (score 1):

Here some rough idea which you can implement

```
 Collections.sort(ArrayList, new Comparator<TreeSet<Integer>>() {
 @Override
            public int compare(TreeSet lhs, TreeSet rhs) {
                // -1 - less than, 1 - greater than, 0 - equal
                return lhs.first().compareTo(rhs.first());
            }
        });
```